# Ionic/Angular and Socket.IO - Show popup upon Socket.IO event received

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, popup, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a real-time mobile application utilizing the Ionic Framework (AngularJS) and Socket.IO.

Coming from a jQuery background, I'm kind of new to the whole Ionic/Angular application design and structure (e.g., controllers, services, etc.). So I was wondering, how should my application be structured, or what is the best/ideal way of structuring my application?

More specifically, in an Ionic/Angular-structured application, where should my usual Socket.IO code go? I've seen one component (https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) which (as I understand) encapsulates Socket.IO code within an Angular factory. Is this the way to go?

What I really want to achieve are the following:

1. Open an (Ionic) popup when a Socket.IO event is received and
2. emit/send a Socket.IO event/message upon a UI event (e.g., button click).

How should my Ionic/Angular code structure look like to achieve this? That is, which code goes into which component/controller/service/factory?

Even a high-level description of the structure would do as a starting point.

Comment: i've gotten the socket.io events to work in controllers before, but a factory or service is probably more ideal

Comment: @SuperVeetz - Thanks! If I place the Socket.IO code within a controller, can it still listen for events in real-time, and subsequently open a popup when one is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example for you, Here's how I did it with a `ChatCtrl` controller.

```
 <!-- app.js -->
 <script>
   angular.module('chatApp', ['ngAnimate'])

   .controller('ChatCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

     var socket = io.connect();

     // on connect, grab username
     socket.on('connect', function(data) {
       nickname = prompt("What's your name?");
       socket.emit('join', nickname);
     });

     socket.on('statusConnected', function(data) {
       $scope.status = data;
       $scope.$apply($scope.status);
     });

   }]);
 </script>
```

My popup is a JavaScript `nickname = prompt("What's your name?")` but you could probably trigger a `modal` or whatever other popup you want with some more JS

Comment: Thanks again, SuperVeetz. Additional questions, if I may, would there be no issues with this setup? Would the socket be able to continuously and successfully listen for events even if the Socket.IO code is within a controller? Can the same controller also be used for emitting events?

Comment: Honestly, i'm not an expert, just trying to stack points and learn/help as I go.. but it probably depends what kind of reusability you want out of the `socket.io` code. If the code is something that will be used accross the entire application, than you will probably want to put it in a `service`, if it's just a small part of the application, a `directive` may be fine

Comment: I see... My requirement is more of the former. Thanks for helping anyway! :)